# How to update a package in /opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to update the h2o package. When I run `conda list h2o`, this package is shown as

```
Name Version  Build  Channel
h2o  3.34.0.3 pypi_0 pypi
```

When I run `conda update h2o` it tells me.

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /opt/conda/anaconda
  package name: h2o
```

How do I update this package?

Comment: it seems you installed h2o with pip instead of conda. This leaves you two options: either update with pip `pip install <pkg-name> --upgrade` or `pip uninstall <pkg-name>` followed by `conda install <pkg-name>`

Comment: @cel that's an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 1):

@cel has correctly answered in his comment, all the credit goes to her/him!

You can see the `conda list` output that the package channel is `pypi`, this means that the package has been installed using `pip`.

If you want to upgrade it in place. This seems to be the simplest solution however mixing `conda` and `pip` packages in a conda environment is not advised since it can lead to dependency issues.

```sh
pip install --upgrade h2o
# check your installation
pip check
# No broken requirements found.
```

If you wan to uninstall it and replace it by a conda package.

```sh
# uninstall it
pip uninstall h2o
# install it with conda
conda install -c conda-forge h2o
```

*Note: I've used the `conda-forge` channel but you can choose to use the default channel.*

Maybe a better / safer solution could be to create a new conda environment from scratch with a fresh version of the package.

```sh
# will create a new env called my-env and containing the latest 
conda create -c conda-forge -n my-env h2o
```

You will need to add also the other packages you need.

Comment: “*all the credit goes to them*” - then this should be a community wiki post